# Printing real-time SSH output using Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

I have a script that SSH connects from Windows7 to a remote ubuntu server and executes a command.  The script returns Ubuntu command output to the Windows cmd window in one go after the command has executed and finished.  I am just wondering if there is anyway to return real-time SSH output in my script below, or do I always have to wait for the command to finish before seeing the output.

Here's my working code:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
host = '9.10.11.12'
port, user, password = 22, 'usr', 'pass'
ssh.connect(host, port,  user, password)
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd /opt/app && ./app-tool some_command")

for line in stdout.readlines():
    print(line)

ssh.close()
```

Alternatively, if this is not possible with SSH how would I introduce a spinning cursor icon into the above script? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out in the end, I used 'iter' method in the following line:

```
for line in iter(stdout.readline,""): 
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of your command seems to less than the default buffer size because of which it is getting flushed once the command completes.

By default the `bufsize` is -1 which means that the system default buffer size is used. If `bufsize` is set to 1 then it is line buffered.

Use

`ssh.exec_command("<cmd>",bufsize=1)`

Comment: Hi SilentMonk, I tried your suggestion but I get the same outcome where the output is dumped at the end of execution.

Comment: oh, what about `bufsize=0`? This means no buffering. Also, what is the size of the output from your command?

Comment: Hi SilentMonk, thanks for your help.  I had a play around and in the end I used the code >>>  for line in iter(stdout.readline,""): print(line)